# IIS ARR - offline installation?

Tags: iis-arr

trying to install IIS ARR, last time did it successful via the web platform online installer,however, our production servers are blocked of all internet connections, any way to do an offline installation of that? Really appreicate the help in advance!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if the server use 64 bit OS, yes you can, just download the below package

https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/confirmation.aspx?id=47332